# Documentset won't automatically tag doucments

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

Has anyone experience this problem before?
It seems that document sets isn't automatically tagging the documents we are adding within. the DS har a custom CT

Comment: From the document set settings you need to specify which columns the DS should share with the documents within.

Comment: Ohhh....Yup that solved it!